# Application not installed in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

When I install my application in debugging mode on my Android mobile device, it seems to be installed.
However, after sending the application  it's not installed on another phone(Android version 8). It says: Application not installed. I tried a few things but cannot resolve this problem.
Does anyone have an idea for device incompatibility.
[image]

Comment: how are you sending the app to the other phone? And how are you installing it? Are you sending the signed APK? Might the other phone be a managed device that will only install apps trusted by the device manager? there is too little info to know what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this solution by making "uninstall the app and install again"

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Settings > Apps > (Your app name). Then press the ellipsis (3 dot button) in the upper right corner then "Uninstall for all users". Then try to install your app again.

If that doesn't work I've found cleaning and building the Android project to work.