# Samsung Galaxy App Not Installed Exception

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I am trying to deploy an update of an existing Mobile application & keep getting the following exception:

> "App Not Installed"

**Q: What am I doing wrong?**
**Q: Is there a way to see or activate ERROR messages?**

**I have the following:**

- Samsung Galaxy S9+
- 42 GB free disk space
- 3 GB memory available
- No SD Card

**I am using the following APK file:**

- com.[companyname].pulse.apk
- ...in my Phone\Download directory
- ...and it shows up in the "Installation Files" listing
- ...this is NOT the signed file (is that right?)

**I have done the following:**

- Gone to "Install Unknown Apps" and verified "Allowed" is checked for "My Files"
- The 1st time I accessed it...I was forced to choose "Allowed"...as well
- Enabled "Developer Options" through the "About Device" menu's

**I developed using:**

- Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.280555))

Comment: Have a look at this discussion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123805/application-not-installed-in-xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my FIRST attempt at any mobile application...so...as it turns out:

- Drop the SIGNED APK file onto your phone
- Install using the SIGNED APK file
- When installing, a PLAY STORE prompt will appear...choose "Install Anyway"

You're done.

To be fair, someone in the office told me to use the UNSIGNED APK file...which turned out to be bogus.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: What am I doing wrong?

The reason may be that there is already an application with the same package name installed by the IDE. You can't install it successfully when you install the same apk with the same package name.  Have a try as follow:

1. Uninstall the installed same app on your phone first.
2. Reinstall the apk app

> Q: Is there a way to see or activate ERROR messages?

You can use **adb** command to check log info in PC or Mac:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

If do not know adb , you can refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).

Comment: Thanks...FYI...the application is definitely NOT already installed.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO Glad you have solved it.Another possible reason can be the Incorrect signature of apk.Remember to mark your answer later : )